# Uniform and Bernoulli and Function of Random Variable

Tags: probability

The question is suppose that $Z$ ~ $Bernoulli(\frac{1}{3})$, $U$ ~ $Uniform (0,1)$. I need to find a function $g$ such that $g: (0,1) \rightarrow R$ such that $g(U)$ is the density of Z that is $g(U) = $ density function of Z, that is $g(U) = (\frac{1}{3})^x(\frac{2}{3})^{1-x}$.

The hint that I am given is that $g(u) = inf\{z: F(z) \geq u \}, 0 < u < 1$ where F here is the density of $Z$ but I am not sure how to apply the hint.

Comment: Looks as if we are simulating $z$, so $g(u)=1$ if $u\le 1/3$, $g(u)=0$ if $u\gt 1/3$.

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite follow.

Comment: The hint is wrong, $F$ is not the density of $Z$, it is the cumulative distribution function. For a general $Z$, the hint would (when corrected) be useful. For Bernoulli, it is a waste of time. We want to simulate a coin that lands heads ($1$) with probability $1/3$, and tails ($0$) with probability $2/3$. So we take a rv $U$ uniform on $(0,1)$, and write head if $0\lt U\le 1/3)$ and tail otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You are welcome. I did not write an answer because I did not want to write out the details of the standard theory about simulating the random variable $W$ using the inverse of the cdf of $W$. Particularly since it is not at all needed for simulating a Bernoulli.

Comment: Can it also be the other way around g(u)=0 if u<=2/3;g(u)=1 if u>2/3?

Comment: Sure, that will work fine too.